# Is there a way to defer undo when the changes are off-screen?

Tags: undo

Let's say I've added some text to some line:

```
some text▊
```

Then I scroll down a bit, so that the line is out of sight:

```
▊
```

When I press undo, I don't want Emacs to delete the line above immediatedly, but only locate it:

```
some text▊
```

And when I press undo a second time it should actually undo it:

```
▊
```

Comment: There is a much better alternative. Use `undo-tree`. It is available from [elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree.html). Therewith you can freely wander around in your undo-activities and don't need to apply any of them. For every undo-action you can see what it **would** do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in the comments I would prefer `undo-tree`.
But, with emacs there is always a way to get what you want.

The following advice of `undo` does what you want in most cases. I think some rare cases cannot be handled.

```el
(defadvice undo (around first-make-change-visible activate)
  "Before actually un-doing make the changed position visible."
  (let (goal)
    (if (listp buffer-undo-list)
    (let ((top buffer-undo-list))
      (while (null (car top))
        (setq top (cdr top)))
      (setq top (car top))
      (cond
       ((and (consp top)
         (number-or-marker-p (car top))
         (number-or-marker-p (cdr top)); insertion starting at (car top) and ending at (cdr top)
         (null (pos-visible-in-window-p (car top)))
         (null (pos-visible-in-window-p (cdr top)))); not visible
        (setq goal (cdr top)))
       ((and (consp top)
         (stringp (car top))
         (numberp (cdr top)); deletion
         (null (pos-visible-in-window-p (cdr top)))); not visible
        (setq goal))
       ((and (consp top)
         (null (car top))
         (symbolp (nth 1 top))
         (number-or-marker-p (nth 3 top))
         (number-or-marker-p (nth-cdr 4 top)); property change
         (null (pos-visible-in-window-p (nth-cdr 4 top))))
        (setq goal (nth-cdr 4 top))))))
    (if goal
    (progn
      (goto-char goal)
      (recenter))
      ad-do-it)))
```